# React Native Navigation Between Different Stacks

Tags: react-native, navigation

How can i Navigate from **Screen1** in **Stack1** to **Screen2** in **Stack2** in React-Native ,Or Navigate from **Stack1** to **Stack2** assuming each stack has its own default start Screen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

```
    navigation.navigate('NameOfTheStack', {
      screen: 'NameOfTheScreen',
      params: {anyParams},
})
```

Make sure that the two stacks are housed under the same Stack Navigator.

Comment: they are hosted in a drawer and i can navigate between the 2 stacks through the Drawer menu ....all i need is when clicking on screen1 in stack1 i want to goto screen2 in stack2